# Who are all the in-universe contributors to the Jedi Path book?

Tags: star-wars

The book, A Jedi Path, had various notes from Jedi contributors.

[image: Signatures on the notes]

I recognise some of the signatures, for instance Anakin and QG (Qui-gon Jinn) But there's some names I don't recognise Ahsok (?) or the red squiggle signature seen below:

[image: the red squiggle signature]

Who are all in-universe contributors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their names are on the frontispiece

[image]

> - [Yoda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda)
> - [Thame Cerulian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thame_Cerulian)
> - [Dooku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku)
> - [Qui-Gon Jinn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn)
> - [Obi-Wan Kenobi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi)
> - [Anakin Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker)
> - [Ahsoka Tano](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano)
> - [Darth Sidious](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious)
> - [Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker)

You may wish to note the *colour* of the handwriting is consistent throughout, as is the distinctive writing style.

There was also a card found in the original "[vault box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0bBgvlsJUY)" that contained a note from Luke Skywalker regarding *when* the various Jedi listed had possession of the book:

> - Master Yoda, the first possessor of this copy, apparently reviewed the pages for revisions in future editions.
> - Jedi Thame Cerulian received the book when he was a child, and it remained in his possession at least through his teens, about 115 BBY to 103 BBY.
> - Dooku, Thame Cerulian's Padawan, took control of the book during his apprenticeship, around 89 to 82 BBY; he later turned to the dark side and took on the title "Count."
> - Qui-Gon Jinn was the next owner, given the book by his Master, Dooku. Qui-Gon's comments appear to date from 82 to 72 BBY.
> - We believe Qui-Gon kept it safe until Obi-Wan Kenobi received the book in 44 BBY.
> - It then passed to Anakin Skywalker in 32 BBY. Anakin owned the book for a 10-year stretch until the start of the Clone Wars.
> - Ahsoka Tano, Anakin's Padawan, held on to the volume, adding her comments during the Clone Wars from 22 to 19 BBY.
> - Darth Sidious - the Sith alias of Emperor Palpatine - acquired the book during the aftermath of the Clone Wars and added his own form of caustic commentary

Comment: You should also put when Luke found it.

Comment: Next time I'm at the book store I'll read it from the beginning....